# How to make Elastic Search API (Query) with count of field and subfeilds

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to get the counts of(SUSPECT and CLEAR) Each State in API using Elastic Search query-
Data inside Elastic Search looks like-
Sample data-

```
{
        "_index" : "index_name"
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "id1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "slflag" : "SUSPECT",
          "state_name" : "UTTAR PRADESH",
        } 



{
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : id2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "slflag" : "CLEAR",
          "state_name" : "UTTAR PRADESH",
        }

{
        "_index" : "index_name"
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "id3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "slflag" : "SUSPECT",
          "state_name" : "Delhi",
        } 



{
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : id4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "slflag" : "CLEAR",
          "state_name" : "Madhya Pradesh",
        }


{
        "_index" : "index_name"
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "id5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "slflag" : "SUSPECT",
          "state_name" : "Rajasthan",
        } 



{
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : id6",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "slflag" : "CLEAR",
          "state_name" : "Bihar",
        }
```

Fields are - state_name, slflag
In slflag field we have two categories - "SUSPECT" and "CLEAR"

I want to make a query to get such results-

```
    {
        "stateName": "UTTAR PRADESH",
        "clear": 688,
        "suspect": 182
    },
    {
        "stateName": "Bihar",
        "clear": 398456,
        "suspect": 117110
    },
    {
        "stateName": "Rajasthan",
        "clear": 688,
        "suspect": 182
    },
    {
        "stateName": "Delhi",
        "clear": 12096,
        "suspect": 984
    }
```

I don't know how to count slflag for each state.

Thanks in advance.

Get /index-

```
{
  "index" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "slflag" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "state_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "wl_d_ind" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1587554261571",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "zFKQmxyTSsyoVLRoCC_3IA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7060199"
        },
        "provided_name" : "index"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried below-

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "states": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state_name.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "flag": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "slflag.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above results in-

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "states" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "UTTAR PRADESH",
          "doc_count" : 5403369,
          "flag" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "CLEAR",
                "doc_count" : 4540278
              },
              {
                "key" : "SUSPECT",
                "doc_count" : 863091
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "RAJASTHAN",
          "doc_count" : 2239768,
          "flag" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "CLEAR",
                "doc_count" : 1866196
              },
              {
                "key" : "SUSPECT",
                "doc_count" : 373572
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "GOA",
          "doc_count" : 12,
          "flag" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "CLEAR",
                "doc_count" : 12
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first aggregate on `stateName` and then on `slflag`, like this:

```
GET index_name/_search?filter_path=**.key,**.doc_count
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "states": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state_name.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "flag": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "slflag.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked but it is not working. Can you please write entire query because I am new to Elastic Search and still exploring.

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping of your index, i.e. what you get from `GET index_name`?

Comment: Added index mapping to the question.

Comment: I've updated the question as you said. Can't I get only fields - state, whether clear or not and count. Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [`filter_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) to achieve what you want, see my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212419/discussion-between-nitinkhatri749-and-val).